# Displaying emails with mutt

Tags: postfix, mutt, fetchmail

After being able to retrieve emails from an IMAP account on a remote mail server using fetchmail and POSTFIX as an MTA, I am able to see the emails in the spool folder `/var/spool/mail/ghassan` in a text file which is called "ghassan". Upon opening mutt I get a note that says

```
"/var/spool/mail/ghassan" is not a mailbox.
```

Any ideas what the reason behind that could be?

How should I proceed

Content of `.muttrc` looks like this:

```
set realname=ghassan
set from =servertest@mcfoxx.de
set use_from = yes
set envelope_from = "yes"
set sendmail="/usr/bin/Postfix"

set spoolfile = /var/spool/mail/ghassan

set folder = "~/Mail"
set record = "+sent"
set postponed = "+postponed"
```

Contents of .procmailrc is the following:

```
#Environment variable assignments

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
VERBOSE=off
MAILDIR=$HOME/Mail
LOGFILE=$HOME/.procmaillog

#Recipes
:0:
* ^TOmutt-user
mutt
```

`ls -ld /var/spool/mail/ghassan` returns the following:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 ghassan mail 27556 Apr 16 12:46 /var/spool/mail/ghassan
```

while `head -1 /var/spool/mail/ghassan` does not return anything.

Comment: It would probably help to post your config file (`~/.muttrc`)? Also, what OS/distribution, please?

Comment: thanks for your comment i just posted the contents of muttrc

Comment: What's the output of `file /var/spool/mail/myname`?

Comment: `/var/spool/mail/myname` vs `/var/spool/mail/ghassan`, what is the correct path?

Comment: the output is basically the content of the text file called "ghassan" when i view it using nano it shows me the emails, but mutt remains empty wit a blank screen and says that it is not a mailbox...

Comment: the correct path is /var/spool/mail/ghassan

Comment: Distribution, please. Also, please specify whether you are doing a local installation of mutt or using your distribution's binary package. Also mention the mutt release version, though that is unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: Do you have a `.procmailrc`? If so, please paste it into the question.

Comment: Please provide `ls -ld /var/spool/mail/ghassan` and also `head -1 /var/spool/mail/ghassan`. As an aside, in your `.procmailrc` should that `VEBOSE` really be `VERBOSE`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

> `head -1 /var/spool/mail/ghassan` does not return anything.

The first line of `/var/spool/mail/ghassan` must be one that starts with `From` (that's the word `From` followed by a space, not a colon) and looks a little like this:

```
From root@somehost.example.net Mon Apr 20 09:48:02 2015
```

You may find that this is the second or third line in the file; delete the leading blank lines from the spool file and try again. (If you're concerned about doing this and destroying the mailbox, run `cp -p /var/spool/mail/ghassan "$HOME/mbox.ghassan"` first.)